# How to debug and find neurons that most influenced a pixel in the output image?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, image-generation

I'm building CNN network of Image to Image.

After training, I have some bad results in part of the Image.

I would like to **find the neurons** that **most influenced those pixels** and do retraining only for them.

I have seen some previous works about visualizing networks, like here:

https://github.com/utkuozbulak/pytorch-cnn-visualizations

But they are only finding activations maps or visualizing with softmax in the output layer.

How can I do that for Image to Image?